# WCF Rest service retunrs different type(string or image) based on input parameters

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, dynamic, stream

I already have a WCF Rest service that returns image(as stream).

```
/rest/getimage
```

and this is my contract is

```
Stream GetImage();
```

and it works fine.

now I want to change this service to accept parameter, based on the parameter, I return image(stream)
or image url(string). something like that:

```
/rest/getimage?format=url|image
```

I changed return type of GetIamge to dynamic and added `[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Stream))]`
but when I call the url in browser ,instead getting image, I got this:

```
<FileStream xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.IO" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><__identity i:nil="true" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System"/></FileStream>
```

the code is the same as working code, I noticed if I changed returning type from Stream to dynamic or object, I got this error.

I cannot add another endpoint(we should have only one endpoint).

Comment: The type returned must either be: a value type, a string, a stream or a serializable type. Dynamic does not have any of those characteristics. Why don't you just add another method? `GetImageUrl(...)`?

Comment: I wanted to add another method  but my client wants this way.

Comment: Ok, clear. Wrap the string inside a stream. The client can take care of the 'unwrapping'. To be more clear, create a `MemoryStream` and write the bytes of the url to that, then return the `Stream` to the client. Only option I can think of.

Comment: thanks, I think this is the only option, I'll let you know.